# Execution of Union in Oracle - Parallel or Sequential?

Tags: oracle

How does a Union in Oracle execute ?

If I have 4 selects in my union statement, will the selects execute in parallel or sequential manner?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on Oracle database version you use and `OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE` initialization parameter.

Shortly: if set to 12.1 (or higher), concurrent  execution is enabled by default. If it is set to a lower version, concurrent execution can be enabled by the `P1_CONCURRENT_UNION` hint.

Documentation: [Concurrent execution of UNION ALL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-1F4C90F9-3EF5-423A-B55B-2593FB3F1433.htm) says:

> Traditionally, set operators are processed in a sequential manner. Individual branches can be processed in serial or parallel, but only one branch at a time, one branch after another. (...)
> The default behavior of concurrent execution for UNION or UNION ALL statements is controlled by the setting of the OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE initialization parameter.

Read the whole document for more info. Also, search for the same subject in other Oracle database version documentation (if it differs from 12c whose link I posted).